# How can I install jdk1.6.0_02 on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos

I want to install JDK 1.6.0_02 on Mac OS. I've tried the Linux version, but it didn't work on Mac OS. How can I install it?

Comment: May still be available on ADC.  Otherwise try just launching "java" in Terminal.app or go to a web page with a Java applet in Safari.

Comment: I searched for it on ADC. It was not found.

Comment: Why do you need that (old) version specifically?

Comment: I need it to do specific testing